# Short Time Discrete Fourier Transform to detect time dependent changes in a frequency of interest & Filter

Tags: filters, phase, fourier, stft

I am working in matlab to compute the fourier relative phase of two signals as per https://sci-hub.tw/10.1123/jab.2017-0250

I have identified the fundamental frequency ($f_1$) for the signals (1.7 Hz) and now the instruction is to "Apply a short-time discrete fourier transform to each window to determine the fourier phase angles of $f_1$ at each time sample. The short time discrete fourier transform can be used to detect time-dependent changes for the frequency of interest and act to filter out potential higher harmonics.

I must run the SDFT for all windows, obtain the phase angles from each window and then transform the phase angles into a continuous time series.

I have read all of the STFT documentation on MATLAB but I can't seem to figure this part out.

Any help is greatly greatly appreciated!

Comment: I checked the Mathworks website -- there doesn't appear to be a "sdft" function.  Moreover, that paper seems to be defining the "relative Fourier phase algorithm", but in a way that makes me suspect they don't quite understand what they're doing.

Comment: And -- the paper is behind a paywall, so I can only judge it by its abstract.  Perhaps you could go into more detail about what it's asking you to do.  Actually determining the relative phase of a fundamental of two signals of known frequency isn't horribly difficult, and isn't made special by using the Fourier transform.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. I have edited the original question with the sci-hub link so you will be able to see the paper beyond the paywall. This is the matlab function I am using: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/stft.html

Comment: This is the method that is recommended to calculate the continuous relative phase for signals that contain many high-frequency harmonics. I want to analyse the variability of the relative phase between gait cycles, however, the resulting relative phase signal is noisy and I am concerned I am introducing greater error into my data, rather than capturing the true variability of the relative phase.

Comment: *Who* recommends this?  What is their basis for recommending it?  How much actual signal processing expertise do they have, vs. reputation in the biomechanics community?  I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, and I've been around the DSP block a few times.